# Symfony redirect all routes ending with on url

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-3.3

Over my Symfony project let us suppose we have the following route:

```
$route= new Route('/my-method',array(
    '_controller'=>'AppBundle:MyController:myMethod'
));
$collection->add('my_method_route',$route);

$route= new Route('/my-method2',array(
    '_controller'=>'AppBundle:MyController:myAnotherMethod'
));
$collection->add('my_method2_route',$route);

$route= new Route('/anotherStuff',array(
    '_controller'=>'AppBundle:MyController:anotherStuff'
));
$collection->add('another_stuff',$route);

$route= new Route('/anotherStuff/{param}',array(
    '_controller'=>'AppBundle:MyController:anotherStuffOneParam'
));
$collection->add('another_stuff',$route);

$route= new Route('/anotherStuff/{param}/{another_param}',array(
    '_controller'=>'AppBundle:MyController:anotherStuffTwoParam'
));
$collection->add('another_stuff',$route);
```

And I want when a url ends with `/` eg. `http//example.com/my-method/` to redirect into `http//example.com/my-method`.

So I was thinking if I can use regex as first parameter on route or to configure thew Symfony's routing system showhow in order to perform, the redirect.

But can Symfony accept a regex or somehow an optional part on url that it casn be ingored? eg to use `'/my-method2/?'` in order to tell that the route may end with `/` and just ignore theese stuff.

Comment: You can do this even at web server level with some configuration: you don't need symfony at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to redirect all url ending by a trailing slash to the same URL withouth right ?

You'll have to create a route that match .*/$ then in the controller remove this "/".

And there is a article that give the code on the symfony doc :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html

Comment: For some reason adds 2 slashes to the redirect url.

Comment: Have you put the route at the end of all you route definitions ?

This code : $url = str_replace($pathInfo, rtrim($pathInfo, ' /'), $requestUri); remove the trailing slash and replace this part in the URL. Seem weird to have two "/" at the end.